# How to prevent the app from going to sleep, in order to integrate a sleep mode for the music

Tags: ios, swift, timer, background-process, sleep-mode

I have a working music App, written in Swift.
I wanted to integrate a sleep mode which could pause the music played after, say 10 minutes.
I used `perform(_ aSelector: Selector, with anArgument: Any?, afterDelay delay: TimeInterval)` for this task, it worked fine.

But there's a problem. There's a good chance that the iPhone'll go to sleep before the 10 minutes end, so the pause fonction isn't called, and the music continues to play.

I understand that there are other ways to send an action after 10 minutes (NSTimer, use GCD) but if I understand, none of this solutions will prevent the machine to go to sleep, or wake up the app to perform the task.

Perhaps I could use [background mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3), but:

1. My goal isn't really in the problems that this mode is supposed to solve. I don't want to have some time to finish, I just want a little 1/10 of second processor at a certain time.
2. This option don't guarantee to work for a 10 minutes period.

Is this a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: You could prevent the device from going to sleep with `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`, but that would probably be throwing the baby out with the bath water.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do: `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`, as this is the only way in Swift 3, and you could do `UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true`in Swift 2 or `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` in objective-c

Comment: This is working, but I have two problems : first this will keep the display on, and that was not mandatory for my purpose. But more important : Is Apple going to validate an app with this setting? (even if I disable it as soon as the app pauses the sound) Others means to obtain the same type of results are allowed only for specific type of Apps by Apple.

Comment: If that isn't what you need, then I am sorry; I do not know otherwise. And yes, Apple would allow it: Ive seen loads of apps with that feature- sorry I wasn't really that helpful.